# Rails - best way to split entries into 4 lists by entry name

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table Groups, where each group has a name like: `4O-101A, 4O-101B, 4O-201A` etc

The fourth char in the name - a number - represents the course number for the group. `40-101A` belongs to course `1`. I want to make 4 html lists for each of 4 courses, so the script should check the fourth char and place the group in the according list.

I tried to make it, but only came up with that ugly solution.
http://pastebin.com/TVBSQ71q
 It has 4 loops and a lot of repeating code, but I want it to be DRY. Can't find a way to achieve it.

Could you please help me? The code should generate 4 lists that look like this one for 1st course

```
<h3>1 course:</h3>
  <ul class='group-list'>
    <%@groups.each do |group|%>
    <% if group.name.slice(3, 1) == '1' %>
          <li id='<%= group.id %>'>
            <button class='ui-list'><%= link_to  group.name , group %></button>
            <% if admin %>
              <div class='btn-con'><%= link_to 'Delete', group, remote: true, method: :delete%></div>
            <% end %>
          </li>
    <%end %>
  <%end%>
  </ul>
```

Comment: The third char in `4O-101A` is a hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would group the `@groups` array using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
@groups_by_course_number = @groups.group_by { |group| group.name[3] }
```

This returns a hash with the course numbers as keys. In your view:

```
<% @groups_by_course_number.each do |course_number, groups| %>
  <h3><%= course_number %> course:</h3>
  <ul class='group-list'>
    <% groups.each do |group| %>
      <li id='<%= group.id %>'>
        ...
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Worked like a breeze! Thank you!